# Save stored procedure results in Dataset using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I use this method to query the database to get all the Valuations of a User. A table is returned with multiple rows and columns

```
 public void UserValuationGet()
 {
    using (FormValueEntities db = new FormValueEntities())
    {
      //Query the database for the Valuation
      var valuation = db.ValuationOfUserGet(userName);         
    }
 }
```

How can I save the valaution in a Dataset or is there any good tutorial on how to use the Entity Framework Complex types?

Comment: Here is a great tutorial on how to use the Entity Framework: [Click Here](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-call-stored-procedure-from-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: There is some Microsoft documentation for automatically building an import function for a complex type. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456824(VS.100).aspx also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/28/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-2-complex-types-deferred-loading-and-explicit-loading.aspx

Comment: Also, if you're looking to store data which is (for example) built up from results from multiple queries - but pass it around the controllers as a single entity - what about a View Model? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3fundamentals_topic7.aspx. For example, you could perform 1 query for a list of the user's favourite songs, another for the last 5 pages they looked at (etc. etc.) and pass it through the controllers like a single model. Is that what you're after? If so, you might be able to use this instead of a stored procedure which returns a dataset.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one-liner for doing this if that's what you are getting at, you would need to manually setup the DataSet & iterate over your query and map the results of your query into it.